# Items wont link to pages

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Each one of my items in this list wont link to other pages. I think I have the  tag in the correct place but it doesnt seem to be functioning.

### HTML:

```
<div class="projectswrap">
    <div class="project project1">
      <a href="www.project1.html">
        <div class="project-hover project-hover1">
          <h2 class="item-title">Rebrand: bla bla bla</h2>
          <h3 class="item-cat">Branding, Identity, Typography, Web Design and Print</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>


    <div class="project project2">
      <a href="www.project2.html">
        <div class="project-hover project-hover2">
          <h2 class="item-title">Gain Theory: Brand and Identity</h2>
          <h3 class="item-cat">Branding, Identity, Web and Print</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>


    <div class="project project3">
      <a href="www.project3.html">
        <div class="project-hover project-hover3">
          <h2 class="item-title">Information Design</h2>
          <h3 class="item-cat">Typography, Information Design, and Print</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>


    <div class="project project4">
      <a href="www.project4.html">
        <div class="project-hover project-hover4">
          <h2 class="item-title">YouGov Competition: "I can't beleaf it"</h2>
          <h3 class="item-cat">Information Design, Layout, Print and Format</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>


    <div class="project project5">
      <a href="www.project5.html">
        <div class="project-hover project-hover5">
          <h2 class="item-title">Embrace's financial handouts</h2>
          <h3 class="item-cat">Layout, Typography and Print</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### CSS:

```
.projectswrap {
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#f7c8c6;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    width:100%
}

.projectswrap .project {
    width:50%;
    padding-bottom:50%;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
    background:#cceaec;
    position:relative
}

.projectswrap .project .project-hover {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    -webkit-transition:all 5.6s ease;
    -moz-transition:all .6s ease;
    -o-transition:all .6s ease;
    -ms-transition:all .6s ease;
    transition:all .6s ease
}

.projectswrap .project:hover .project-hover {
    display:block
}

.item-title {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:xx-large;
    font-weight:700
}

.item-cat {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:50px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:medium;
    font-weight:100
}
```

Ideally, when you click each one of these project boxes, they should link to the projects page.

Comment: Why do you have `display: none` for the elements inside the link?

Comment: You don't have the tag in the correct place. The `<a>` is an inline element, while `<div>` and `<hX>` elemets are block. Try to work it out correctly, then it will work.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Though ugly, in HTML5 `<a>` is allowed to wrap block level elements.

Comment: here http://plnkr.co/edit/uK9waHmXhjvUEYfljkzb?p=preview your `<a>` tags are work correctly.what is your problem exactly?

Comment: and why are you using so many `position: absolute` ?? is it really necessary ?

Comment: @connexo I know that, I hate it too! `:(` W3C gone mad.

Comment: Does anyone know why they dropped the universal `href` attribute which was originally planned for all HTML 5 elements?

Comment: The reason for display none is that I have a hover state on each project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files you are linking to are in the same folder as the file you quoted above, simply remove the www:

```
<a href="project1.html">
```

If they're in a different directory, link to the directory:

```
<a href="another_directory/project2.html">
```

If they're in a different website, link with `http://` and the full domain path:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/project2.html">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add either **http** or **https** before links

For example www.example.com should be written as http://www.example.com inside of href attributes

EDIT : Www.example.com is a relative link. While http://www.example.com is proper link to another website(absolute links)

Comment: Yes you can add all those. But if you omit http that means link is associated with you website... Like www.example.com would redirect to http://you-website-current-page-directory/www.example.com.